# Convert from Byte array to a List

Tags: c#, arrays, list, byte

I'm converting a `List<string>` into a byte array like this:

```
Byte[] bArray = userList
                .SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByte(s))
                .ToArray();
```

How can I convert it back to a `List<string>`? I tried using `ASCII.GetString(s)` in the code above, but `GetString` expected a `byte[]`, not a single byte.

Comment: You need some way to split your giant byte stream into multiple strings.

Comment: Something like `bArray.ToList()`? Or does your original list have multiple strings in it?

Comment: The original list has multiple strings but I'm not sure how to split it. Alternatively, is there a better way to convert a list of strings to/from a byte array or stream?

Comment: Why are you doing this again?

Comment: For a prototype, I have a method which can only accept a byte array or a stream (the parameter types can't be changed for now, only the method itself). I need to send the method a `List<string>` so I tried to convert it to a byte array.

Comment: @Skoder, `is there a better way to convert a list of strings to/from a byte array or stream` Yes this is called `serialization`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to reverse your algorithm.

The problem can be seen if you consider what happens when you have two users called "ab" and "c". This will give the exact same bytes as if you have two users called "a" and "bc". There is no way to distinguish between these two cases with your approach.

Instead of inventing your own serialization format you could just the [serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9.aspx) that is built into the .NET framework, such as the [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I'll use a serializer. Since I had the code above, I thought I may have been missing something simple in order to reverse the process. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

As a bit of a sidenote, if you preserve the zero-byte string termination you can easily concatenate the strings and extract all information, e.g.

```
Byte[] bArray = userList
    .SelectMany(s => System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s + '\0')) // Add 0 byte
    .ToArray();

List<string> names = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < bArray.Length; i++)
{
    int end = i;
    while (bArray[end] != 0) // Scan for zero byte
        end++;
    var length = end - i;
    var word = new byte[length];
    Array.Copy(bArray, i, word, 0, length);
    names.Add(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(word));
    i += length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert a delimter between your strings so that you can split the big byte array back into the original users. The delimiter should be a character which cannot be part of a user name.

Example (assuming `|` cannot be part of a user name):

```
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByte(string.Join("|", userList.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this since the delimiters of the array structure were lost in the `SelectMany` method.